# Array inside function returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I practice simple js lessons and have problem with this part below
Function should return array index 0 instead of letter A but actually returns - undefined
And i cant figure it why ?

```
function parseGuesses(guess) {
    var alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"];
    if (guess === null || guess.length !== 2) {
        alert("Ups proszę podać literę i cyfrę");
    } else { firstChar = guess.charAt(0);
        var row = alphabet.indexOf(firstChar);
    }
}
console.log(parseGuesses("A2"));
```

Comment: You don't use the [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) keyword, so nothing will be returned.

Comment: Also `firstChar` should be declared with `var` or preferably `let`.

Answer (score 1):

As Ivar said the function you wrote isn't returning anything so by default it would return `undefine` so to change the return value of the function you should write it like so:

```
function parseGuesses(guess) {
  var alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"];
  if (guess === null || guess.length !== 2) {
    alert("Ups proszę podać literę i cyfrę");
  } else {
    let firstChar = guess.charAt(0); // you should also declare when you create a new variable
    return alphabet.indexOf(firstChar);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It logs undefined because your function does not return anything.

Your function should have return keyword typically used at last line of the function like this.

```
function parseGuesses(guess) {

  // operation of something ....

  return something
}
```

Then logs it to the console

```
console.log(parseGuesses("A2"))
```

Modified from you code

```
 function parseGuesses(guess) {
  var alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];
  let firstChar, row;
  if (!guess || guess.length > 2) {
    alert('Ups proszę podać literę i cyfrę');
  } else {
    firstChar = guess.charAt(0);
    row = alphabet.indexOf(firstChar);
  }
  return [firstChar, row]; // return an array after those operation above
}
console.log(parseGuesses('A2'));
```